# WCF client can't connect to non WCF named pipe server

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF named pipe server, a non WCF named pipe server, a WCF named pipe client and a non wcf named pipe client.

The non WCF client can connect to both servers.  The WCF client can only connect to the WCF server.  When I try to connect it to the non WCF client I get this exception.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint
listening at net.pipe://localhost/PipePlusFive that could accept the message. This is 
often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException,
if present, for more details. ---> System.IO.PipeException: The pipe endpoint 
'net.pipe://localhost/PipePlusFive' could not be found on your local machine.
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

According [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20151116055104/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rodneyviana/archive/2011/03/22/named-pipes-in-wcf-are-named-but-not-by-you-and-how-to-find-the-actual-windows-object-name.aspx) the actual name of a pipe is a guid stored in a memory mapped file.  I assume this is handled automagically for the WCF client and server.  for the non WCF server I create the memory mapped file, write a guid to it, then create the pipe using that guid for the name.  In the non WCF client I open the memory mapped file, read the pipe name from it, and then use that name to connect to the pipe. Then fact I can connect to both servers using the non WCF client without changing anything leads me to believe that I'm implementing this part correctly on both the server and the client.

Also when I start the non WCF server then start the WCF server the second crashes stating that it cannot listen on that pipe name because another endpoint is already listening.

I'm wondering why the WCF client can't find the non WCF server when the non WCF client can find both?  is there something else WCF uses to find an end point besides what is described in the blog I linked to?

UPDATE:

Here is the code I'm using for the WCF client:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ChannelFactory<IPlusFive> pipeFactory =
            new ChannelFactory<IPlusFive>(new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None), new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/PipePlusFive"));
       
        IPlusFive pipeProxy = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();

        while (true)
        {
            string str = Console.ReadLine();
            if (str.Equals("q"))
            { return; }
            Console.WriteLine(pipeProxy.PlusFive(Int32.Parse(str)));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code I'm using for the WCF server:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var inst = new PlusFiver();
        using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(inst,
            new Uri[] { new Uri("net.pipe://localhost") }))
        {
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IPlusFive), new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None), "PipePlusFive");
            host.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Service is Available. Press enter to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            host.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code that I'm using for the non WCF server:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Creating Memory Mapped file...");
        string fileName = GenerateFileMapName(String.Empty);
        Guid pipeName = Guid.NewGuid();
        Console.WriteLine(" writing pipe name: " + pipeName.ToString("D"));
        MemoryMappedFile mmf = null;
        var messageList = new List<byte>();
        try
        {
            mmf = WritePipeName(fileName, pipeName);
            Console.WriteLine("Creating Named Pipe");
            Console.WriteLine("Pipe Name: " + GetPipeNameFromMappedFile(fileName, mmf));
            using (var pipe = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipeName.ToString("D"), PipeDirection.InOut))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("pipe created");
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connection");
                pipe.WaitForConnection();
                Console.WriteLine("Received Connection");
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting to receive data");
                var bytes = new byte[7];
                pipe.Read(bytes, 0, 7);
                messageList.AddRange(bytes);
                bytes = new byte[messageList[6]];
                pipe.Read(bytes, 0, messageList[6]);
                messageList.AddRange(bytes);
                bytes = new byte[2];
                pipe.Read(bytes, 0, 2);
                messageList.AddRange(bytes);
                messageList.Add((byte)pipe.ReadByte());
                pipe.WriteByte(0x0b);
                WriteList(messageList);
                Console.WriteLine("Finished reading from pipe");
                PrintBytes(bytes);
                Console.WriteLine("Closing Connection");
                pipe.Disconnect();
                Console.WriteLine("Pipe disconnected");
                //Console.Read();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            mmf.Dispose();
        }

    }

    private static void WriteList(List<byte> messageList)
    {
        foreach (var b in messageList)
        {
            Console.Write(b.ToString("x2") + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    private static void PrintBytes(byte[] bytes)
    {
        foreach (var b in bytes)
        {
            Console.Write(b.ToString("x2") + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    private static string GenerateFileMapName(string uri)
    {
        return "net.pipe:EbmV0LnBpcGU6Ly8rLw==";
    }

    private static MemoryMappedFile WritePipeName(string fileName, Guid pipeName)
    {
        var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew(fileName, pipeName.ToByteArray().Count());
        
            Console.WriteLine("Memory Mapped File Created.");
            using (var accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor(4, 45))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Writing pipe name to file");
                accessor.Write(0, ref pipeName);
                Console.WriteLine("Finished writing pipe name to file");
            }
        return mmf;
    }

    private static string GetPipeNameFromMappedFile(string filename, MemoryMappedFile mmf)
    {
        Guid pipeName;
        using (var accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor(4, 45))
        {

            accessor.Read<Guid>(0, out pipeName);
        }
        return pipeName.ToString("D");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WCF endpoint netNamedPipeBinding is designed to connect to WCF named pipe server. When WCF client established connection using this type of binding it makes the same preparations as specified in [the article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rodneyviana/archive/2011/03/22/named-pipes-in-wcf-are-named-but-not-by-you-and-how-to-find-the-actual-windows-object-name.aspx) you mentioned. That [post](http://blogs.charteris.com/blogs/chrisdi/archive/2008/05/19/exploring-the-wcf-named-pipe-binding-part-1.aspx) will clarify the rest details.

Comment: I've added my code.  Can you see where I'm doing something wrong?